# Exclude records that have sum greater than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, case

I have query returning details of customers that are subscribed to channel xyz or all other channels.
To generate this results i am using the following query:

```
select customerID
,sum(case when channel='xyz' then 1 else 0 end) as 'xyz Count'
,sum(case when channel<>'xyz' then bundle_qty else 0 end) as 'Other'
From temptable
```

So my Question is, how do i Exclude customers that are subscribed to 2 channels, where one is xyz and one is another channel.

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  How do you count customers who are subscribed to one channel multiple times?

Comment: Subscribed to exactly two channels and of those one and only one is channel 'xyz'?

Answer (score 1):

```
select customerID
      ,sum(case when channel='xyz' then 1 else 0 end) as 'xyz Count'
      ,sum(case when channel<>'xyz' then bundle_qty else 0 end) as 'Other'
From temptable
group by customerID
having sum(case when channel= 'xyz' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when channel<>'xyz' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your query is not correct.  It needs a `group by`.  Second, you can do what you want using `having`:

```
select customerID,
       sum(case when channel = 'xyz' then 1 else 0 end) as xyz_Count,
       sum(case when channel<>'xyz' then bundle_qty else 0 end) as Other
From temptable
group by customerID
having count(*) = 2 and
       sum(case when channel = 'xyz' then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

If customers can subscribe to the same channel multiple times, and you still want only "xyz" and another channel, then:

```
having count(distinct channel) = 2 and
       (min(channel) = 'xyz' or max(channel) = 'xyz')
```